# C#: Json to Object: Getting error ex = {"Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path 'result', line 1, position 12."}

Tags: c#, .net, json, data-conversion

I'm not sure if I setup my class wrong or not causing the error. I'm pretty new to working with Json.

Function code:

```
Response = OpenIDM.GetUserInformation(email, fields);
            LDAPMembership = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LDAPMembership>(Response);

            string id = LDAPMembership._id;
```

class:

```
public class LDAPMembership
{
    public string[] result { get; set; }
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public string _rev { get; set; }
    public string[] ahaMemberGroup { get; set; }
    public string[] ahaDrupalPermissions { get; set; }
    public string resultCount { get; set; }
    public string pagedResultsCookie { get; set; }
    public string totalPagedResultsPolicy { get; set; }
    public string totalPagedResults { get; set; }
    public string remainingPagedResults { get; set; }
}
```

Json String:

```
{\"result\":[{\"_id\":\"98d0d0b9-9506-40b4-84c4-e005d4bc25ec\",\"_rev\":\"1\",\"ahaMemberGroup\":[\"AONE\",\"AHA\"]}],\"resultCount\":1,\"pagedResultsCookie\":null,\"totalPagedResultsPolicy\":\"NONE\",\"totalPagedResults\":-1,\"remainingPagedResults\":-1}
```

Exception being thrown:
Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path 'result', line 1, position 12."}

I suspect I did not setup "result" correctly in my class. I searched around and found a similar issue and tried the response but that did not work.

Error gets thrown on this line:

```
LDAPMembership = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LDAPMembership>(Response);
```

Comment: Are all those backslashes a result of showing the json with the debugger, or does your json file actually contain those characters?

Comment: First look: `result` is not an array of strings. But of somethingthat has an `_id`.

Comment: Result is not an array of strings, it is an array of complex objects. The JSON does not match the object to which you are trying to deserialize.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen - considering the error points to 'position 12` the actual JSon text is probably Ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio can do this for you. Get the clean JSON (without all those `\"`),   put that Json on your clipboard, place your cursor in a C# file and select

> Edit, Paste Special, Classes from JSon

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Result[] result { get; set; }
    public int resultCount { get; set; }
    public object pagedResultsCookie { get; set; }
    public string totalPagedResultsPolicy { get; set; }
    public int totalPagedResults { get; set; }
    public int remainingPagedResults { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public string _rev { get; set; }
    public string[] ahaMemberGroup { get; set; }
}
```

Use as-is or clean up a little. Change `Rootobject` to whatever you like.
Note that you'd probaly want to fix the type of pagedResultsCookie .

Comment: Good catch changing the counts to int as well.

Comment: I didn't do that. This is straight from VS.

Comment: I didn't realize you'd used Paste Special at the time of commenting. They really should be integers according to the JSON formatting, so it made the right decision, IMO. (If you notice, in OP, the class definition has them as strings when they are not.)

Comment: Yes, but it needs more/better data to figure out what the pagedResultsCookie  is.

Comment: Ah, you're right. Yeah, considering it only had null to work with, it made the best choice it could.

Comment: Thank you so much, I totally get it now. I don't think paste special was the best way to describe the answer but the snippet really explained my issue. Thank you for helping.

Comment: Can you show how to get the membership groups out of that class? This is what I came up with but I don't think its right: for (int i = 0; i < LDAPMembership.result.GetLength(0); i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < LDAPMembership.result.GetLength(1); j++)
                    {
                        System.Console.Write("{3} ", LDAPMembership.result);
                    }
                }

Comment: `.result.GetLength(1)` makes no sense, replace it with `.result.Length`